# Nothing to summarize if you provide a single RasterLayer; see cellStats

Tags: raster, r, optimization

I'm trying to optimize 5 coefficients from 2 rasters. To do so I tried to use the optim function doing this :

```
CHLOA = raster(("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif"), band = 1)
B1 = raster(("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif"), band = 2)
B2 = raster(("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif"), band = 3)
B3 = raster(("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif"), band = 4)
ratio = max(B1, B2)/B3

Modis = raster("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26.tif")

crop1 = crop(ratio, Modis)
crop2 = crop(Modis, ratio)
resample = resample(crop1, crop2, "bilinear")
stack = stack(resample, crop2)

min.RSS = function(data, par){
  with(data, sum((stack$chlor_a-(par[1]+par[2]*stack$layer+par[3]*stack$layer^2+par[4]*stack$layer^3+par[5]*stack$layer^4))^2))
}

optim(par=c(0,1,2,3,4), fn=min.RSS, data = stack)
```

But I got this error :

> Erreur dans optim(par = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), fn = min.RSS, data = stack)
> :    pas de méthode pour convertir automatiquement cette classe S4 en
> vecteur De plus : Message d'avis : Dans sum() :   Nothing to summarize
> if you provide a single RasterLayer; see cellStats

Can someone help me to handle it ?

Comment: Please always edit closed questions to provide more details so they can be reviewed for re-opening rather than re-asking them: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/470001/115

Comment: I deleted the last qusetion because it was not clear at all

Comment: Please don't delete your questions when they are unclear.  Instead, you should edit them.  Deleting questions is risky because it feeds into the algorithms for automated question bans.

Comment: Ok, did not know I will pay attention to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `min.RSS` function is doing a sum on a raster, and that returns a raster, and optim wants a global single value, I assume this is a sum over cells.

I would take the values of the cells and convert to vectors outside the optimisation, and then the `optim` is only working on vectors and doesn't need to do any raster conversion or extraction to get the data. I think this will work:

```
stack_v = list(chlor_a=values(stack$chlor_a),
               layer=values(stack$layer))
```

or actually maybe you don't need to stack them in the first place, so make the list of values from the originals:

```
stack_v = list(chlor_a = values(resample), layer = values(crop2)
```

(Side note: calling things the same name as functions is generally not a good idea...)

Then rewrite `min.RSS`:

```
min.RSS = function(data, par){
# this is a function of *data* not *stack*.
   sum(
    data$chlor_a - 
    (par[1]+par[2]*data$layer +
     par[3]*data$layer^2 +
     par[4]*data$layer^3 + 
     par[5]*data$layer^4)^2)
 }
```

Then run optim passing `stack_v` as data, which is what gets passed into the minimised function `min.RSS`:

```
> optim(par=c(0,1,2,3,4), fn=min.RSS, data = stack_v)
$par
[1]  3.443787e+21  2.787680e+21 -2.199424e+20 -1.814071e+20 -4.350456e+21

$value
[1] -2.11901e+44
[etc]
```

Nonsense values here because I'm using 3x4 random rasters but this should show the principle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got this error when trying to use it with my rasters : the function cannot be evaluated at the initial parameters. Can this be made by the NA data ?

Comment: Saw that this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068213/error-in-optim-function-cannot-be-evaluated-at-initial-parameters could be the cause but here I'm using par as a vector a coefficients so I don't understand why it is not working

Comment: Yes, its a symptom of an NA in your data. Use `sum(..., na.rm=TRUE)` to ignore NA values in the summation. Your function should probably be a function(par, data) instead of function(data,par) since optim will be varying the parameters in par as the first argument in the call - but you might be getting away with it if it calls by name anyway.